# Using eigenvalues and vectors as preconditioner for iterative linear solver

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I am solving the linear system $Ax = b$, where $A \in C^{n\times n}$, $b \in C^{n\times 1}$. A is a sparse, non-diagonally dominant & non-symmetric matrix.

I have a good estimate, although not an exact solution, of the k-rank SVD of the matrix $A^{-1}$. Where, $k << n$ i.e I have a good estimate of the $k$ smallest singular values (and their associated vectors) of $A$ i.e a good estimate of the $k$ largest singular values (and their associated vectors) of the matrix $A^{-1}$.

Is there a method where I can use this information I have about the SVD to help me solve the linear system? Either through using it as a pre-conditioner for an iterative solver, or otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: I had a slightly similar problem once. I used the [preconditioned conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method) in that case. However, my matrix was symmetric, and I think I had the largest, not the smallest singular values of $A$, and I think that was what made the preconditioning effective. For non-symmetric matrices there is the [biconjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconjugate_gradient_method), but Wikipedia claims it's numerically unstable.

Comment: Thanks @Joriki for your answer. I am wondering, how did you use the singular values of A as a preconditioner for PCG?

Comment: It's in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268970210133206) (that's behind a paywall; unfortunately I don't have the PDF at hand, it's been a while...) -- the matrix basically had the form $T+V$, where $T$ was diagonal in the basis I used and dominated the large eigenvalues. I applied the method roughly as described in the Wikipedia article, using $T$ as the preconditioner $M$.

Comment: Perhaps you can solve (or find an approximate solution) to $\tilde A x = b$ (where $\tilde A$ is your low-rank approximation to $A$) and use that as an initial estimate to something iterative like a Krylov-subspace method.